# Sql Insert Trigger with counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a trigger for a database I'm currently working on but have very little experience creating these. The trigger is for an insert command but if the number of inserts on one UserId is higher than 30 I need to add anything after that to another table called audit. Where would I start?

```
CREATE  TRIGGER trigger_audit
On INSERT
   ON Persons
   [ FOR EACH ROW ]
DECLARE
   -- variable declarations
BEGIN
   -- trigger code
EXCEPTION
   WHEN ...
   -- exception handling
END;
```

Comment: We can use myDatabase as an example

Comment: I mean like sql server,mysql,oracle...

Comment: I know I need something like if inserted count is higher than 30 insert into table audit where userid = userId?

Comment: what version of sql server. I started to right an answer and realized it might be different if depending on version.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.16518
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.5477
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: hmm. The SSMS version probably is what came with 2008, but you could be connecting to a different SQL Server version. You could check that by checking the properties of the server not the help/about of the SSMS.

Comment: 10.50.2550.0 is the version I believe I can always change it accordingly

Comment: That's sql server 2008 R2 for what is worth.

Answer (score 0):

"Where would I start?"

I would start with something like this:

```
WITH UserInserts AS (
 SELECT [SomeUniqueId]
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY [Something_Maybe_SomeUniqueId]) rn
   FROM INSERTED
)
INSERT INTO Audit 
SELECT <your fields> 
  FROM INSERTED i 
       INNER JOIN
       UserInserts u ON i.[SomeUniqueId] = u.[SomeUniqueId]
 WHERE u.rn > 30
```

That using a CTE to number the inserts per user and then "auditing" anything with a row number > 30.
Obviously incomplete, but if you start there and get stuck we can help more.